# Match column A button with column B panel c#

Tags: c#, button, match, panel

I have made an drag and drop program where i move a button into a panel, like in this picture below, but i don't know how to verify if panel1 contains button1, because i want to make a program where to match items from column A to column B(match buttons x to panel x and verify if all matches were right: button1 in panel1, button2 in panel2...).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace proiect_istorie
{
    public partial class DragAndDrop : Form
    {
        public DragAndDrop()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = ((Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button)));
            bt.Parent = (Panel)sender;
            bt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            bt.BringToFront();
        }

        private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Button bt = (sender as Button);
            bt.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

and i have associated with every button and panel an event like in the pictures, and i don't know how to verify if the matches were right button1 in panel1...

[event on panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Uye.png)

[event on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0hKF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your button and your Panel to the same string you can use the following code to verify if the panels and buttons on them match:

```
private void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.Text = "";

    // loop over all controls of the Form
    foreach(var ctl in Controls)
    {
        var pnl = ctl as Panel;
        if (pnl != null)
        {
            // loop over the Controls in a Panel
            foreach(var pnlctl in pnl.Controls)
            {
                // find any buttons
                var bt = pnlctl as Button;
                if (bt != null)
                {
                    // check if the Tag property of the Panel matches that of the Button
                    textbox.AppendText( pnl.Name + " = " + ((bt.Tag ==  pnl.Tag)?"OK": "Not OK") + "\r\n");                
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

This is how it looks in action:

[image: drag and drop]

I left it as an exercise to implement the handling when no or more the one button are dropped on the panel.